# What is the benefit of marking function as IMMUTABLE?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I was looking through some of the [plpgsql](/questions/tagged/plpgsql) functions in our codebase and realized that most of them cannot be set [`IMMUTABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) only because they contain reference to `now()`, e.g.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_nearest_time (
  target_times time without time zone[],
  target_dows int[],
  timezone_name text
)
RETURNS timestamp with time zone
AS $$
DECLARE
  target_time time without time zone;
  nearest_time timestamp with time zone;
  next_time timestamp with time zone;
BEGIN
  IF (
    array_length(target_times, 1) = 0 OR
    array_length(target_dows, 1) = 0
  ) THEN
    RETURN null;
  END IF;

  FOR add_day IN 0..6
  LOOP
    FOREACH target_time IN ARRAY find_nearest_time.target_times
    LOOP
      next_time := (date_trunc('day', (now() at time zone find_nearest_time.timezone_name) - target_time::interval) + interval '1 day' + target_time::interval) at time zone find_nearest_time.timezone_name;
      next_time := next_time + interval '1 day' * add_day;

      IF (
        extract(isodow from next_time) = ANY(target_dows) AND
        (
          nearest_time IS NULL OR
          nearest_time > next_time
        )
      ) THEN
        nearest_time := next_time;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;

    IF (nearest_time IS NOT NULL) THEN
      RETURN nearest_time;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN next_time;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, we can easily rewrite the above function to where `now()` is passed as a parameter, e.g.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_nearest_time (
  seed_time timestamp with time zone,
  target_times time without time zone[],
  target_dows int[],
  timezone_name text
)
RETURNS timestamp with time zone
AS $$
DECLARE
  target_time time without time zone;
  nearest_time timestamp with time zone;
  next_time timestamp with time zone;
BEGIN
  IF (
    array_length(target_times, 1) = 0 OR
    array_length(target_dows, 1) = 0
  ) THEN
    RETURN null;
  END IF;

  FOR add_day IN 0..6
  LOOP
    FOREACH target_time IN ARRAY find_nearest_time.target_times
    LOOP
      next_time := (date_trunc('day', (find_nearest_time.seed_time at time zone find_nearest_time.timezone_name) - target_time::interval) + interval '1 day' + target_time::interval) at time zone find_nearest_time.timezone_name;
      next_time := next_time + interval '1 day' * add_day;

      IF (
        extract(isodow from next_time) = ANY(target_dows) AND
        (
          nearest_time IS NULL OR
          nearest_time > next_time
        )
      ) THEN
        nearest_time := next_time;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;

    IF (nearest_time IS NOT NULL) THEN
      RETURN nearest_time;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN next_time;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE;
```

This way the function can be marked as `IMMUTABLE`.

What is the benefit of marking function as `IMMUTABLE` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL documentation [37.7. Function Volatility Categories](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) states the following on using the `IMMUTABLE` keyword with functions:

> An IMMUTABLE function cannot modify the database and is guaranteed to
> return the same results given the same arguments forever. This
> category allows the optimizer to pre-evaluate the function when a
> query calls it with constant arguments. For example, a query like
> SELECT ... WHERE x = 2 + 2 can be simplified on sight to SELECT ...
> WHERE x = 4, because the function underlying the integer addition
> operator is marked IMMUTABLE.
>
> For best optimization results, you should label your functions with
> the strictest volatility category that is valid for them.

In short, the stricter volatility keyword you can use in your function definitions, the more optimized they'll perform in your queries. I suspect this is especially true when using the `IMMUTABLE` keyword because of it guaranteeing the function is determinsitic as stated here:

> ...guaranteed to return the same results given the same arguments
> forever.